# Riddle: I can be this, and you can be this, and, yes, we can be this

Tags: riddle, word

> I can be this, and you can be this.
>   And, yes, we can be this.
>   He can't be this and she can't be this.
>   And no, they can't be this.
>   Dogs can't be this, but cats can.
>   And a kitten can't be this, but a puppy can.
>   Givers can't be this, but beggars can.
>   And humility can't be this, but greed can.
>   Not even peace can be this, but fear can.
>
> What am I?

Source: I don't know where I originally saw this as it was many years ago.  But this might be the [original source](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_medium;action=display;num=1043696901), posted in 2003.

Comment: Today I learned that I've been rot13(glcvat) wrong all this time, I always rot13(cerff gur o xrl jvgu zl evtug unaq).

Comment: Now I think about it, so do I!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These things can be

> fully typed with just one hand on a QWERTY keyboard, in the standard touch typing position. The words that cannot be this all require the usage of both hands.

Comment: Very good :) Have you heard this before, or did you work it out really quickly? (It had me stumped for ages.)

Comment: @Earlien I've heard so many other riddles about rot13(xrlobneq erfgevpgvbaf) that rot13(glcvat bhg gur jbeqf) is one of the first things I try if nothing comes to mind.